# FatalErrorException in Facade.php line 216: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::missing()

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5

---

I have an issue with a mix of Laravel and Angular routing while trying to catch my non-Laravel routes and present the Angular view..

I got the below error when I added missing method in my app\http\route.php :

FatalErrorException in Facade.php line 216: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::missing()

I know this will work fine with laravel 5 or down version but not with laravel 5.2 which I am using currently, so how to code in laravel 5.2 ? Any solution ?

---

route.php looks like :

```
<?php // app/routes.php
// HOME PAGE ===================================  
// I am not using Laravel Blade 
// I will return a PHP file that will hold all of our Angular content

Route::get('/', function() {   
    View::make('index'); // will return app/views/index.php 
});
// API ROUTES ==================================  
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {

    // Angular will handle both of those forms
    // this ensures that a user can't access api/create or api/edit when there's nothing there
    Route::resource('comments', 'CommentController', 
        ['only' => ['index', 'store', 'destroy']]);

});

// CATCH ALL ROUTE =============================  
// all routes that are not home or api will be redirected to the frontend 
// this allows angular to route them

App::missing(function($exception) { 
    return View::make('index'); 
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**App::missing()** has been removed in Laravel 5. You need to define a catch-all route yourself, just make sure you put it at the end of your **routes.php**:

```
Route::any('{catchall}', function() {
  //some code
})->where('catchall', '.*');
```

Comment: Thanks it works well...and even I found the solution for this on laracast channel. Thanks for your comment..

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/laravel-5-catch-all-route-appmissing-handle?page=1

Comment: was having the same problem but implemented this and its now working fine. thanks @jedrzej.kurylo

Comment: YEAH! YOU ROCK MAN! YOU ROCK! THIS IS IT!